# Implementar otro tipo de notificación de resultados de operaciones con registros

Tags: php, html, html5, semantic-ui

El título parece algo extraño pero la cuestión es la siguiente: Tengo un formulario donde el usuario ingresa datos y al concluir apreta un botón GUARDAR. El formulario lo tengo vinculado a otro archivo PHP donde proceso la información y realizo el impacto sobre la base de datos.
Ahora bien, cuando el resultado de la operación de grabación muestro un mensaje todo adornado con semantic ui. Pero este mensaje me queda sobre esa pagina guardar.php y no sobre la que contenía el formulario. Hago esto en el body de la pagina guardar.php

```
<body>
<div style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%">
    <div class="ui green segment">
        <?php if($resultado) { ?>
            <h3>Registro guardado satisfactoriamente</h3>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <h3>Hubo un error al intentar guardar el registro</h3>
        <?php } ?>
        <a href="eventos.php" class="ui red button">Regresar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

le tengo que plantar un botón que diga volver a la pagina madre, por decirlo de alguna forma... 
Mi consulta es: existe forma de que pueda hacer que este mensaje de esta página sea en realidad un mensaje modal de la otra pagina donde esta el formulario ? 
es medio loco lo que planteo ? 
se podra hacer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es enviar la información por AJAX y obtener un resultado de esta solicitud (si fue guardado o no).

Al recibir dicha información simplemente mostrar una especie de popup, que ya depende como lo desees implementar.

Voy a sugerir un ejemplo que encontré en internet con jQuery y [SweetAlert2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) (uno de mis favoritos para mostrar popups):

```
$("#formulario").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post( "guardar.php", function() {
      swal("Registro guardado", "Muy bien", "success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      swal("Ups", "Hubo un error", "error");
    });

});
```

Comment: Exacto... pero eso lo hago en el guardar.php ? porque el action del form me llama al guardar.php... es como que pierdo el foco del formulario... que lindo que esta el SweetAlert !!!

Comment: No, lo haces en el archivo donde está el formulario.

Comment: ahhhhhh posterior al form ?... osea termino el tag del form y lo coloco ahi ?

Comment: Bueno, lo agregas entre tags `<script>...</script>`, idealmente antes de cerrar `</body>`

Comment: claro... seguro... entre los tags script... SHAZ !!! MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS !!!

Comment: Shaz, sabes que implementé perfecto el sweetalert2... salvo por un pequeño inconveniente... no me grabó el registro !!! jajajajajajaja y lo peor es que me dice que el proceso fue correcto...

Comment: Bueno, realmente depende de la solicitud ajax más que de sweetalert, revisa lo que entregas y obtienes de ajax, probablemente debas devolver un `true / false` o un json, depende lo que necesites.

Comment: En realidad esta devolviendo un true porque tengo esto: $sql = (query de insert) y despues $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql); y lo que evaluaba en el guardar.php era el resultado de esa variable $resultado

Comment: tendria que poner un evaluador de esa sentencia $resultado, pero cómo lo devuelvo ?